# How to read Data from Firebase in android studio using kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to get The name of the user and his email from the database, i use this to set the data to the database :

> createUser

```
fun createUser( name:String, email: String, password: String) {

    mProgressbar.setMessage("Please wait..")
    mProgressbar.show()


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val user = User(
                    name,
                    email
                )

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Void> { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            val Intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(Intent)
                            finish()
                            mProgressbar.dismiss()
                        } else {
                            //display a failure message
                        }
                    })
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.${task.exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mProgressbar.dismiss()

            }
        }
}
```

> User

```
class User ( name: String,  email: String) {

    private var name: String? = name
    private var email: String? = email

    fun setName(Name: String) {
        this.name = Name
    }
    fun getName(): String? {
        return name
    }
    fun setEmail(Email: String) {
        this.email = Email
    }
    fun getEmail(): String? {
        return email
    }
}
```

I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Code to get values from database

```
val menuListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // handle error
    }
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
        textView.text = user?.name
    }
}
```

> and i have to change User Class code to:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    var name: String? = "",
    var email: String? = ""
) {

    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "uid" to name,
            "author" to email
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
internal var user: User? = null  // declare user object outside onCreate Method

var ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)

val menuListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        user = dataSnapshot.getValue() as User
        textView.text = user?.getName()
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // handle error
    }
}
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(menuListener)
```

Comment: can you give it to me in kotlin please

Comment: user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)

Comment: e = " Name Expected " ?

Comment: @WIKOSO I updated the code. Hope this will solve the issue

Comment: please tell me now if i want to get the user name what i need to do :

Comment: textView.text = user?.getName()

Comment: What's the error you're getting? I updated the code check that

Comment: the text View is not changing

Comment: Can you check whether the user variable has got the value in `user = dataSnapshot.getValue() as User`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193565/discussion-between-wikoso-and-sanoj).

Comment: Hey bro can you help in this issue please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454480/how-to-fix-firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class-using-kotlin